# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I don't think we can use limit laws here and look at the limits individually because $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is undefined at $0$. I think it requires the squeeze theorem but I'm not sure how to apply the Squeeze Theorem; do I need to define an interval or cluster point?

What I have so far: $$g(x)= x\sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$ $$h(x)=x$$

I can't find a $f(x)$ such that, $$f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$$ $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} h(x) = 0$$

Am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: consider $f(x)=-x$

Comment: You might want the absolute-value function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
For any value of $x$, you know that $-1\leq \sin(1/x)\leq 1$. Multiply this equation by $x$.

Comment: Does the inequality hold when multiplying by $x$ even when $x<0$?

Comment: When $x<0$, the inequality reverses, of course, but it still helps you. You just have to separate the cases.

Comment: @Shad0wNinja: a trick when you don't want to bother with sign is to consider absolute values: we have $|\sin(\frac{1}{x})|\leqslant 1$, so $|x\sin(\frac{1}{x})|\geqslant|x|$. Since $\lim_{x\to 0}|x|=0$, then, by Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x\to 0}|x\sin(\frac{1}{x})|=0$. This implies (this is a theorem) that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$.

All works here mostly because the final limit is $0$.

Comment: It should be $|x\sin(\frac{1}{x})|\leqslant|x|$ in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $-1 \leq \sin \frac{1}{x} \leq 1$ for all $x \neq 0$ to produce functions $f, h$ to which you can apply the Squeeze Theorem.